# I have a mysql server attached to wordpress and it keep maxium out and running this query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

I have a mysql server attached to wordpress and it keeps maximum out the server running this query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdfeP.png)

Can some give me some advice on how to address this and fix or what the issue or why this is being done
Thanks

Comment: Query runtime is 3 seconds, which is not quick, but is hardly the end of the world. Tryimg to optimise a query generated by an application is difficult since you can't influence the query itself and the app expects certain data structures to be in place as well. You can try adding some indexes, but in case of a restore, you may lose those.

Comment: Suggest installing this plugin:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)  If that does not suffice, please provide a _text_ version of the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.